# How to run this program?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, fork

I can compile this program which was provided to me, but that I must further develop. I have some questions about it:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define TIMEOUT (20)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pid_t pid;
  if(argc > 1 && strncmp(argv[1], "-help", strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: RunSafe Prog [CommandLineArgs]\n\nRunSafe takes as arguments:\nthe program to be run (Prog) and its command line arguments (CommandLineArgs) (if any)\n\nRunSafe will execute Prog with its command line arguments and\nterminate it and any remaining childprocesses after %d seconds\n", TIMEOUT);
      exit(0);
    }

  if((pid = fork()) == 0)        /* Fork off child */
    {
      execvp(argv[1], argv+1);
      fprintf(stderr,"RunSafe failed to execute: %s\n",argv[1]);
      perror("Reason");
      kill(getppid(),SIGKILL);   /* kill waiting parent */
      exit(errno);               /* execvp failed, no child - exit immediately */
    }
  else if(pid != -1)
    {
      sleep(TIMEOUT);
      if(kill(0,0) == 0)         /* are there processes left? */
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"\nRunSafe: Attempting to kill remaining (child) processes\n");
      kill(0, SIGKILL);      /* send SIGKILL to all child processes */
    }
    }
  else
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"RunSafe failed to fork off child process\n");
      perror("Reason");
        }

}
```

What does my warning mean when I compile it?

```
$ gcc -o RunSafe RunSafe.c -lm 
RunSafe.c: In function ‘main’:
RunSafe.c:30:44: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
```

Why can't I execute the file?

```
$ file RunSafe
RunSafe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x0a128c8d71e16bfde4dbc316bdc329e4860a195f, not stripped
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Lexar$ sudo chmod 777 RunSafe
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Lexar$ ./RunSafe
bash: ./RunSafe: Permission denied
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Lexar$ sudo ./RunSafe
sudo: ./RunSafe: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to `#include <string.h>` to get rid of that warning.

Second, the OS is probably preventing you from executing programs on the `/media/Lexar` filesystem, no matter what their permission bits are. If you type `mount` you'll probably see the `noexec` option for `/media/Lexar`.

Comment: Adding to @Greg's response I believe if the `noexec` option isnt the mount option, the `/media/Lexar` may a different type of file system, probably FAT or something else.

Comment: Simply being FAT normally isn't enough to prevent execution.

Comment: Well, indeed the OS will not run the program if its on FAT.  Although chmod will succeed, the executable bit will not be set.  Hence the shell will complain permission denied.

Comment: Thanks, it works now after following your instruction. You are completely right: I was on FAT32 (USB) and just moving the project to regular filesystem made everything work.

Answer (score 1):

> warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]

You need to include `#include<string.h>` because `strlen()` is declared in it.

Try running the exe on some other location in your filesystem and not the mounted partition as the error indicates for some reason you don't have permissions on that mounted partition.

Comment: You're right. It works now after following these instructions. Thanks for the answer.